# Prefilling customer address with Paypal Buttons

Tags: javascript, paypal

This is how my paypal button code looks like

```
paypal.Buttons({
createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    // Set up the transaction
    return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
            amount: {
                value: '{{total_formatted}}',
                currency_code: '{{currency_iso}}'
            }
        }]
    });
},
style: {
    size: 'responsive',
    color: 'blue',
    shape: 'pill',
},
onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    // Capture the funds from the transaction
    return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        // Show a success message to your buyer
        window.location.href = 'Some place';
    });
}
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

The user has to fill in his billing / shipping address. Is there a way to pre-fill those for him?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The following will work:

```
return actions.order.create({
    payer: {
        name: {
            given_name: "{{first_name}}",
            surname: "{{last_name}}",
        },
        email_address: "{{email}}",
        phone: {
            phone_type: "MOBILE",
            phone_number: {
                national_number: "{{telephone}}",
            }
        },
        address: {
            address_line_1: "{{billing_address1}}",
            address_line_2: "{{billing_address2}}", 
            admin_area_1: "{{billing_town_city}}", 
            admin_area_2: "{{billing_county}}", 
            postal_code: "{{billing_postcode}}",
            country_code: "GB"
        }
    },
    purchase_units: [{
        shipping: {
            name: {
                full_name: "{{first_name}} {{last_name}}",
            },
            address: {
                address_line_1: "{{shipping_address1}}",
                address_line_2: "{{shipping_address2}}", 
                admin_area_1: "{{shipping_town_city}}", 
                admin_area_2: "{{shipping_county}}", 
                postal_code: "{{shipping_postcode}}",
                country_code: "GB"
            }
        },
        amount: {
            value: '{{total_formatted}}',
            currency_code: '{{currency_iso}}'
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I've read [the docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/#4-set-up-the-transaction) and i think you could do this, try it and let me know if it worked

```js
paypal.Buttons({
createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    // Set up the transaction
    return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
            amount: {
                value: '{{total_formatted}}',
                currency_code: '{{currency_iso}}'
            }
        }],
        shipping: {
          method: "United States Postal Service",
          address: {
            name: {
              give_name:"John",
              surname:"Doe"
            },
            address_line_1: "123 Townsend St",
            address_line_2: "Floor 6",
            admin_area_2: "San Francisco",
            admin_area_1: "CA",
            postal_code: "94107",
            country_code: "US"
          }
        }
    });
},
style: {
    size: 'responsive',
    color: 'blue',
    shape: 'pill',
},
onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    // Capture the funds from the transaction
    return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        // Show a success message to your buyer
        window.location.href = 'Some place';
    });
}
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Comment: The details you are providing are for "shipping" but the credit card form's fields are "billing", so it does not populate them.